# Can anyone help me out in dependency Injection?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, roboguice

```
public class Apple {  
    private final Orange orange;  
    private final Pear pear;  
    private final Banana banana;  

    public Apple(Orange orange, Pear pear, Banana banana) {  
        this.orange = orange;  
        this.pear = pear;  
        this.banana = banana;  
    }  

    // methods  
}
```

This is my POJO class. Now, I do the instantiation part in my onClick Method.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Apple apple = new Apple(myOrange, aPear, theBanana);   
        new AppleAsyncTask(apple ).execute();
    })
};
```

How can I avoid this instantiation part and do something better using Dependency Injection? Or is what I'm doing right?

Comment: The question is: How do you calculate what orange/pear/banana your apple (fruit salad might be a better name...) should hold?

For me what you are doing looks completetly valid, though i can imagine cases, in which dependency injection might be a better choice.

Comment: @DThought: Can u give me an example of this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about injecting Apple into AppleAsynTask then what you have done is correct. Dependency Injection is a type of [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). There are other ways you could instantiate the Apple outside of this program. For example you could use a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern) or a [service locator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern)

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
      new AppleAsyncTask(AppleFactory.getApple(myOrange, aPear, theBanana)).execute();
  })
};
```

What you are doing looks good to me.

Comment: Can you give me the example of this using either factor or service locator... i am in android.

Comment: @theJava Ive just done a quick search on Google. This link may help to describe how you can implement Factory http://javapapers.com/design-patterns/factory-method-pattern/